# Castear valor entero en execute - PHP PDO

Tags: php, sql, pdo

Tengo una funcion la cual le paso una query y los parametros directamente:

```
public function sql($query, $arrayFiltros){
            try {

                $datos = [ "totalRegistros" => 0, "columnas" => [], "registros" => [] ];
                $consulta = $this->prepare("companies", $query);
                $consulta->execute($arrayFiltros);

                $datos["registros"] = $consulta->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                $datos["totalRegistros"] = $this->totalRegistros($consulta);
                $datos["columnas"] = $this->columnasDatatable($consulta);
                $this->db->closeConnect();
                return $datos;

            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                error_log($e->getMessage());
                return NULL;
            }
        }
```

Esta funcion me sirve para enviar dinamicamente consultas a la base de datos y de momento me ha funcionado super bien... El asunto viene al momento en que debo pasar valores enteros, pero el `execute` los toma como string, ejemplo en esta query `select * from Company where Id = :id`, yo envio como filtro `["id_compania" => intval($id_compania)]`, pero no me toma el valor como un entero...

La idea es poder usar el `execute` como "gatillador" y no tener que llenar de parametros BindValue o BindParam.

Espero se pueda entender y me puedan ayudar.

Comment: Si no haces *bind* no tiene sentido usar una sentencia preparada, y mucho menos dentro de una función. ¿Por qué dices que lo toma como entero?.

Comment: Lo que comento es que parametros que envio como entero no me los toma en la query como entero, los toma como si fuese string... ejemplo :id_compania si fuese `4`, en la query lo reemplaza como '4'. Y como especifique, no uso sentencias `bind` porque la idea es enviar queries dinamicas a esa funcion y enviar los parametros directamente como array

Comment: Si no haces *bind* esas comillas simples no salen ni de PDO ni de MySQL; pareciera que el problema viene de la misma clase del método `sql()`.

Comment: Como agregado, estas son las opciones que paso a PDO `[PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false]` y estoy usando SQL Server